# testing sails/mysql with fixtures primary key issue

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a sails app working against a legacy database (MySQL) and I would like to perform integration tests. I am using fixtures to load data into a separate test database using barrels. When I run my tests I get an error:

```
[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  Error:   ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Interview.js `api/models/Interview.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'interview',
    attributes: {
        interviewId: {
            type: 'integer',
            columnName: 'interview_id',
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        ...

    }
};
```

interview.json `tests/fixtures`:

```
[
   {
    "interviewId": 1,
    "title": "some string",
    "createdDate": "2015-11-23T09:09:03.000Z",
    "lastModified": "2015-11-23T09:09:03.000Z"
   },
   {...}
]
```

test environment `config/env/test.js` :

```
  models: {
    connection: 'test',
    migrate: 'drop',
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false
  }
```

The problem seems to lie in defining a primary key in the schema rather than letting sails create one automatically. If I remove the interviewId field from the model and set `autoPK: true` it works. But this does not accurately represent my data structure.

App info:
`sails@0.11.2` `sails-mysql@0.11.2` `waterline@0.10.27` `barrels@1.6.2` `node v0.12.7`

Many thanks, 
Andy

Comment: I have just tried this with version `0.12.0-rc3` and it works as expected

Comment: in your model.js you have migrate: "alter" ?